# React native youtube - component not visible

Tags: react-native, youtube

I cannot see the player, when mounting to my page:

```
return (
    <YouTube
      apiKey="xxx"
      videoId={youtubeVideo} // The YouTube video ID
      play={false} // control playback of video with true/false
      fullscreen={false} // control whether the video should play in fullscreen or inline
      loop={false} // control whether the video should loop when ended
      onReady={e =>  console.log('ready')}
      onChangeState={e =>  console.log('onchange')}
      onChangeQuality={e =>  console.log('change quality')}
      onError={e => console.log(e.error)}
      style={{ alignSelf: "stretch", height: 300 }}
    />

);
```

I get console logs for the `onReady` callback but no video. How can I display my video?

Are there any better alternatives? Having looked into these two packages, `react-native-youtube` and `react-native-vimeo`. Both haven't been maintained for a while and have various issues.

What is the best way to embed video from youtube that fits guidelines for both Play and App Stores? With lots of video based apps on the Play stores, how does everyone else do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your YouTube component wrapped inside a parent view with flex ? I'm using the same package in my app and it seems to be working fine and this is pretty much how I've got it set up.

```
// Parent view (page container)
<View style={{ flex : 1 }}>
    ...
    <Youtube 
        apiKey={API_KEY}
        videoId={videoID}
        style={{ marginTop : 15, height : 250, alignSelf : 'stretch' }} />
    ...
</View>
```

Comment: I get `UNAUTHORIZED_OVERLAY` an my video keeps pausing. I am using a nested `Stack` for each page in a `Drawer` using `React-navigation`

Comment: Hmm, I checked over at the [repo](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube) and this seems to be a known [issue](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube#known-issues). It seems to happen when another component covers the YouTube component. Here is a [link](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube/issues/161) to the bug report containing possible fixes.